# How to show FireFox extension popup only on specific websites?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to show my popup only on a specific website. This was easily achieved for chrome:

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
    conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
      pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'www.mywebsite.com'},
    })
    ],
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
  }]);
});
```

Unfortunately, declarativeContent is not supported on FireFox. I tried the following:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.match("www.overleaf.com")) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
  }else{
    chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
  }
});
```

The behaviour is inconsistent. Sometimes it is shown, sometimes it is not. Switching tabs sometimes makes the plugin disappear without it reappearing again. How can I get the same behaviour as on Chrome.

Comment: Firefox has a better solution, `show_matches` in manifest.json, see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/page_action#Syntax).